# postgres: How to protect conditional expressions from null values

Tags: sql, postgresql, short-circuiting

After years of using Postgresql, I still don't know if there is an established best-practice on how to protect conditional expressions from null values of variables, given that SQL query planners have full authority to apply or ignore the most frequently used idiom to protect from null values: "var is null or var=0".

Allegedly, using the 'case when ... end' grammar solves any ambiguity, but also reduces maintainability, since it obscures with lots of words a simple procedure.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: `var==null` doesnt work I think you mean `var IS NULL`

Comment: Im not sure what is your question and wont mark it as duplicated, but this is the usual way we handle null parameter on conditional expresion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078637/sql-function-with-parameters-that-may-be-null

Comment: Yeah, you are right,  the idiom "var==null || var==0" is Java code and I failed to state that. Also failed to state that in Java (and many other non-sql languages),  the short-circuit of the second boolean expression is forced by the language specification, meaning that if the first "var==null" is true, then the second "var==0" is not evaluated.

Comment: You dont get that short cirtcuit on sql. You have to do it like the sample I show you. Or you can check this version http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/09/18/sql-conditional-where-clauses.aspx

Comment: Not sure what it would do for performance but you could use [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html). From your example: `COALESCE(var, 0) = 0`. You could also take the inverse of that with `NULLIF`, ie. `NULLIF(var, 0) IS NULL`

Comment: No short-circuiting is required. `var = 0 or var is null` works fine. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is: (to my knowledge, ) in SQL the expression "var = 0" will evaluate to null if var is null.  But you want to get a boolean result, so, in java (for example), you protect it with a short-circuit:  "var == null || var == 0".  The problem is than in SQL all subexpressions may be arbitrarily reordered, and short-circuits may have effect or not.

Comment: Igor - The solution you mention seems to me to be enough :  just use coalesce(), nullif() is null.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a missconception arising from comparing SQL to Java (or C, C++, or any language dealing with *references* or *pointers*).

You don't *need* to *protect* conditional expressions from `NULL` values when working with SQL.

In SQL, you do not have (hidden) pointers (or references) to objects that should be tested against NULL or otherwise they cannot be dereferenced. In SQL, every expression produces a certain *value* of a certain *type*. This value can be `NULL` (also called `UNKNOWN`).

If your `var` is `NULL`, then `var = 0` will evaluate to `NULL` (*unknown* = 0 gives back *unknown*). Then `var IS NULL` (*unknown* is *unknown*) will evaluate to `TRUE`. And, according to three-value logic, `TRUE or UNKNOWN` evaluates to `TRUE`. No matter which is the order of evaluation, the result is always the same.

You can check it just by evaluating:

```
SELECT
    /* var */ NULL = 0 as null_equals_zero,
    /* var */ NULL IS NULL as null_is_null,
    TRUE or NULL AS true_or_null,
    (NULL = 0) OR (NULL IS NULL) AS your_case_when_var_is_null,
    (NULL IS NULL) OR (NULL = 0) AS the_same_reordered
    ;
```

Returns

```
null_equals_zero | null_is_null | true_or_null | your_case_when_var_is_null | the_same_reordered
:--------------- | :----------- | :----------- | :------------------------- | :-----------------
null             | t            | t            | t                          | t
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=28ce16d8bf48579d8fe08413dfe549ab)*

Given `var` = 0, NULL and 1 (<> 0); you'll get:

```
WITH vals(var) AS
(
    VALUES
    (0),
    (NULL),
    (1)
)
SELECT
    var,
    var = 0 OR var IS NULL  AS var_equals_zero_or_var_is_null,
    var IS NULL OR var = 0  AS var_is_null_or_var_equals_zero,
    CASE WHEN var IS NULL then true
         WHEN var = 0 then true
         ELSE false
    END                     AS the_same_with_protection
FROM
    vals ;
```

```
 var | var_equals_zero_or_var_is_null | var_is_null_or_var_equals_zero | the_same_with_protection
---: | :----------------------------- | :----------------------------- | :-----------------------
   0 | t                              | t                              | t                       
null | t                              | t                              | t                       
   1 | f                              | f                              | f
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3c898bf8001d5feae3c17dcbad17e4d5)*

These are the basic truth tables for the different operators (NOT, AND, OR, IS NULL, XOR, IMPLIES) using [three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic), and checked with SQL:

```
WITH three_values(x) AS
(
VALUES 
   (NULL), (FALSE), (TRUE)
)
SELECT
   a, b, 
   a = NULL AS a_equals_null,  -- This is alwaus NULL
   a IS NULL AS a_is_null,     -- This is NEVER NULL
   a OR  b AS a_or_b,          -- This is UNKNOWN if both are
   a AND b AS a_and_b,         -- This is UNKNOWN if any is
   NOT a   AS not_a,           -- This is UNKNOWN if a is
   (a OR b) AND NOT (a AND b) AS a_xor_b,   -- Unknown when any is unknown
   /* (a AND NOT b) OR (NOT a AND b) a_xor_b_v2, */
   NOT a OR b  AS a_implies_b  -- Kleener and Priests logic
FROM
   three_values AS x(a)
   CROSS JOIN
   three_values AS y(b);
```

This is the truth table:

```
a    | b    | a_equals_null | a_is_null | a_or_b | a_and_b | not_a | a_xor_b | a_implies_b
:--- | :--- | :------------ | :-------- | :----- | :------ | :---- | :------ | :----------
null | null | null          | t         | null   | null    | null  | null    | null       
null | f    | null          | t         | null   | f       | null  | null    | null       
null | t    | null          | t         | t      | null    | null  | null    | t          
f    | null | null          | f         | null   | f       | t     | null    | t          
f    | f    | null          | f         | f      | f       | t     | f       | t          
f    | t    | null          | f         | t      | f       | t     | t       | t          
t    | null | null          | f         | t      | null    | f     | null    | null       
t    | f    | null          | f         | t      | f       | f     | t       | f          
t    | t    | null          | f         | t      | t       | f     | f       | t
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a94cb2f0de5b635a008e7e8b7b2cc087)*

Comment: joanolo, hi.  Thanks for you response.  If I understand correctly, the logical operators AND, OR, NOT, return NULL if any of their operands is null.  Thus , the NULL propagates.  This is what I want to "protect", but without verbosity to keep maintainability.

Comment: Sentence above should state that NULL propagates to UNKNOWN ... the effect would be the same, I guess.  The problem is handsomely describen in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Null_propagation

Answer (score 0):

It seems I just asked a question which has forever been present.  So, per de problem of NULL propagation in SQL logical expressions, with the added danger of the sql optimizer not honoring short-circuit constructs, and of evolving SQL standards, let me share what I've found so far:

1. Read wikipedia's article on [SQL NULL PROPAGATION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Null_propagation)
2. Use [coalesce()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html) around any column name with possible null values, involved in any calculation within a sql statement (thanks [Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1260204/igor)).
3. Also use 'is [not] distinct from' instead of '=' or '<>'